# How do I check divisibility in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python script right now to check if a number a Wilson Prime, but it says I have a syntax error on line 9.

I've tried both the mod function with x%y == 0 and x/y == int, but both of them have given me a syntax error.

```py
n = int(input("Type a natural number here"))
fact = 1

for i in range(1,n):
fact = fact * i

finalfact = fact + 1

if finalfact % n == 0
    print(n, "is a prime number!")

if (finalfact/n) % n == 0
    print(n, "is also a Wilson Prime!")
```

I'm trying to make it check if (n-1)!+1 is divisible by n (which is a way to find prime numbers) and to check if (n-1)!+1 is divisible by n^2 (Wilson Primes), but it gives me a syntax error on line 9 and nothing happens.

Comment: `x % y == 0` works, but an [if statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) requires a colon.

Comment: And don't forget to properly indent.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `:` at the end of `if` statements.

Change:

```
if finalfact % n == 0
```

To:

```
if finalfact % n == 0:
```

And:

```
if (finalfact/n) % n == 0
```

To:

```
 if (finalfact/n) % n == 0:
```

---

Need to indent the code properly:

Change:

```
for i in range(1,n):
fact = fact * i
```

To:

```
for i in range(1,n):
    fact = fact * i
```

---

Also:

```
finalfact / n     # 5 / 2 = 2.5
```

Should be:

```
finalfact // n    # 5 // 2 = 2
```

Comment: yes, thank you. I started very recently so I forgot this. it works now

Comment: Welcome! If this answers your question, then feel free to mark it as accepted.